# Why is the charge density of a rod in $\rm C/m$ and not in $\rm C/m^2$?

Tags: charge, dimensional-analysis, density, si-units

Is it because we consider the rod to be a 1-dimensional straight line? Or is there any other reason? I know it sounds like a stupid question but I am confused in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any number of dimensions you can define a density.

In 1-D you can have a charge length density, charge per length.

In 2-D you can have a charge area density, charge per area.

In 3-D you can have a charge volume density, charge per volume.

Frequently, these are all shortened and referred to in a single confusing way: charge density.

Charge on a rod can be described using any of these 3 densities. In your case, it was provided as a charge-per-length, likely because that would be the most useful for the given problem. It is indeed possible that you would like to treat the rod as a 1-D thin line.